# Removing N/A from table in Python with none - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'where'

Tags: python, na, nonetype

I have a table in python with multiple columns with N/A and i want to replace those with None or blank if possible. I have tried many ways but i got all the time this message :

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'where'
```

I have tried this :

```
 main = main_df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
 print(main)
```

and also tried this :

```
 main = main_df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

and this :

```
main = main_df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
print(main)
```

Whatever i am trying the messege is the same : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'where' or 'replace'

Do you have any idea how should i do that ? I am desperate to fix this . Appreciate all the help ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not caused here - the error you're given, means that the value of `main_df` is `None`.

The easiest way to detect what is causing the problem is to use `print(main_df)` whenever it's changed (including the line where it's first declared), and see where it starts to be `None`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It was as you said , now it's working

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error message, it tells you that `main_df`, which is of type `NoneType` does not have `where` attribute.
This is probably because you have done something like this:

```
main_df = main_df.some_function(inplace=True)
```

See, pandas methods with `inplace=True` don't return anything. Just remove this argument and it should work