# How use two column values on a dataframe and store the result in a new one

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to choose two column values for example bananas (from column "fruit") who are not from Italy (from column "country of origin") and store it in a new dataframe.

approach:

```
a = df[(df['fruit'] == "banana") & (df['country of origin'] != "Italy")].index
df.drop(a, inplace=True)
```

When I run this code I get this error message:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I would be very grateful for help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing N/A from table in Python with none - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'where'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960524/removing-n-a-from-table-in-python-with-none-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. We can't run your code, because you didn't provide the dataframe. Just give a couple of rows of your dataframe with which the code should work. Right now, the error message is saying that you are trying to subscript (meaning x['y']) a NoneType object. So your variable `df` has to be None for some reason we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

just add the subset of the original df in a new variable.

```py
>>> df
    fruit country of origin
0  banana     Farao Islands
1  banana             Italy
>>> b = df[(df['fruit'] == "banana") & (df['country of origin'] != "Italy")].copy(deep=True)
>>> b
    fruit country of origin
0  banana     Farao Islands
```

Use `.copy(deep=True)` if you want to ensure the slice will not be a view but a copy of the data. However, take care if your dataframes are large as it will use much more memory.